# Is $\left\{ F\subseteq V | P(F) \right\} = \emptyset$ or $= \left\{ \emptyset \right\} $, if no $F$ satisfies $P$?

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory

Let $V$ be a set and let $P$ be a property, such that for no $F\subseteq V, \ P(F)$ is true.

Is then $\left\{ F\subseteq V | P(F) \right\} = \emptyset$ or $= \left\{ \emptyset \right\} $ ?

Comment: If $\emptyset$ is in the set then $P(\emptyset)$ must be true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A=\{F\subseteq V\mid P(F)\}=\{\varnothing\}$ then it means that $\varnothing\in A$, therefore $P(\varnothing)$ is true.

If *no* set is such that the property holds, then $A=\varnothing$, i.e. it has *no elements*.